# Having trouble with Retina image size in Email

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, dpi, retina, dimensions

I just got a new imac.

When I opened up an old email design in Photoshop it was small. I saw that I was zoomed at 100% so this was confusing at first before I remembered RETINA...

I redesigned an email with a width of 1200px which appears like a 600px container in Photoshop at 100% zoom.

When I save the image as a .jpg and drop it into an email (inline or attached) to share with client for feedback, the image is huge.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried reducing the size of the image by 50% back to a 600px container, which looks properly sized for an email when I attach the file to an email, but it's blurry (even at 144 DPI)

Can't wrap my head around this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard how the image looks on your screen in Photoshop, it's a pretty well-known issue and although I keep reading Adobe has addressed it, I still seem to have an issue with it.

you can always zoom to 200% for a better look at how a browser/email client will render it.

Either way, **don't increase the size of your images**.  Emails are still typically designed at 600px wide.  600px is 600px, despite how it looks on your monitor.